# JTextField dosen't properly insert characters

Tags: java, swing

I am currently trying to make a calculator in `java`. I created all the number buttons, operations,number display, etc. I also added the function to every button. Everything were working well. Then I added a button through which I could insert a dot(decimal point). But this is not properly getting inserted in `JTextField`. Here is the `actionPerfomed()` for button 1, and `dot` button....

```
one.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        numdisp.setText(numdisp.getText()+one.getText()); //numdisp is the number displayer(JTextField)

    }


//Other buttons like button2,button3,button4,etc.... are not mentioned as they have the same set of code....

dot.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    numdisp.setText(dot.getText()+numdisp.getText());
    });
```

[Download the jar file here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/7bjcdo4fyoc5uev/Calculator2.jar?dl=0)

When you press the `one` button the `JTextField` shows the number 1. Then press the `dot` button. The `JTextField` shows "1.". Everything is good till now. Then press 1 again. The expected result is "1.1" but instead It displays "11.". Why is this weird problem occurring? How to fix it?

Comment: You are adding the dot *before* the existing string. You should add it in the same order that you do in the number.

Comment: numdisp.setText(numdisp.getText()+".");

Comment: I think the flow+result you explain is not conform the code you pasted.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your ActionListeners is different. In one case you add the text of the button at the beginning. In the other case you add the text of the button at the end.

So a better solution is to not use different ActionListeners, but to share the same ActionListener, so the logic will be same for all buttons and you don't have to create multiple listeners. This way you are less likely to make mistakes.

Check out [setText method with panel and button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414654/settext-method-with-panel-and-button/30414727#30414727). This example will show you how to:

1. create a single ActionListener to be shared by each button
2. "append" the text to the text field instead of replacing the text
3. use Key Bindings so the user can also just type the number