# Java GUI adding buttons with a for loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi i am making a lotto gui where the user picks 4 numbers from a selection of 28. The way i am currently doing it is as follows

```
private void no1InputButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    numberSelectionList.add("1");
}                                              

private void no2InputButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
     chosenNumDisplayLabel.setText(chosenNumDisplayLabel.getText()+" 2");
}                                              

private void no3InputButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
     chosenNumDisplayLabel.setText(chosenNumDisplayLabel.getText()+" 3");
}
```

etc up through the 28 numbers.

- Is there a way to add the actions to each button through a for loop
  as this seems more logical?
- Also is there a way to add each number picked into an array?

Answer (score 1):

Create a single Action that can be shared by all buttons. The Action will then simply get the text of the button and then do some processing.

Check out [setText method with panel and button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414654/settext-method-with-panel-and-button/30414727#30414727). This example will show you how to:

1. create a single ActionListener to be shared by each button
2. "append" the text to the text field instead of replacing the text
3. use Key Bindings so the user can also just type the number

Answer (score 0):

On each button you can set an action command:

```
 button.setActionCommand("1");
```

And you can get the value after that using your ActionEvent:

```
 evt.getActionEvent();
```

More complete:

```
  ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
  {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand()+" clicked");
     }
  };

  int howMuchYouWant = 32;
  for(int i = 0; i<howMuchYouWant; i++)
  {
     JButton button = new JButton(""+(i+1));
     button.setActionCommand(""+i);
     button.addActionListener(listener);
     //add to whatever gui you want here
  }
```

Comment: how many button i can generate with this? he need to generate 28 button and each one should have an event so your answer for one button :)